# AngularJS, save data in a json and retrieve it allowing angular to rebuild a dynamic table

Tags: javascript, angularjs, persistence

Good morning Everyone:
My angular app is a restaurant manager. Somwhere in the backend it shows a restaurant delivery manager, where delivery costs can be managed. I'm giving the option to the users (Restaurant admins) in the backend ui to add Delivery methods, and locations, so each combination has a price and it's saved to the json and displayed in a table below the inputs using ng-repeat

My json is something like this:

```
{
  "deliveryLocation": [
                       {
                         "id": 1,
                         "location": "downtown"
                       }
                      ],
  "deliveryMethods":    [
                         {
                           "id": 1,
                           "name": "Delivery Boy"
                         },
                         {
                           "id": 2,
                           "name": "Cab"
                         }
                        ],
  "combinations":       []

}
```

So when you populate the inputs, you will have at least a combination, for ex: "Downtown - Cab". That combination will be stored in "combinations" (see json) with the following format: "deliveryLocation": "", "deliveryMethods": "", "price": 0

Where price will be an empty input in the combinations table. So the user indicates how much that delivery will cost and that will be saved in the combinations array. (For ex: "deliveryLocation": "downtown", "deliveryMethods": "cab", "price": 50).

I must send the data to the backend when the user saves the table. When the user opens the delivery manager again, the app will receive the data from the backend, will receive the same json, recovering deliveryLocations and deliveryMethods it's quite straightforward, but how should I indicate to AngularJS that everything that will be found in the combinations field is a combination of references? (deliveryLocation an deliveryMethods).

Thanks so much,

Guillermo

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. Why should AngularJS know that some objects are related? Why you store full names, not IDs of objects? Why you need ID at all if locations and delivery methods names are unique?

Comment: Please, delete your description of logic. No one is going to read all your post.

Comment: OZ_ thanks for your answer, I'll take some of your suggestions, in the other hand. The user can build dinamically a table of delivery options to show to the users.
So suppose, that you access the first time, and add a destination, a method, then in the table below you add the price.
That table will reflect any change in your inputs, so if you change a destination name, it will change in your table

Answer (score 1):

1st off take a look on this good example: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SAWsA/11/)

This example demonstrates how to convert JSON object to table with angularjs.

So what you need to do:

1) with angular send your table object to your (suppose PHP) server side to DB by using some factory:

```
module.factory('ajax_post', ['$http',  function(_http) {   

var path = 'src/php/data.ajax.php'; // example

return{
    init: function(jsonData){
        var _promise= _http.post(path, 
            jsonData
            ,{
                headers: {
                    'SOAPActions': 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/UpdateListItems'
                }
            }
            );            
        return _promise; 
    }
  }   
}]);
```

By the same way load table from DB.

Comment: Maxim, I finally fixed my issue. What I did: When the user submits the form, all the data in the angular table is sent as a json (processed through a method), just raw data, not hashkeys.

When I get the info from the server, I process the data backwards to fit my needs to build the dynamic tables. Thanks a lot for your help.